# Angular: Component styles do not cascade to sub-components?

Tags: css, angular, sass

In my *app.component.html* I have the following, working class assignment.

```
<body>
  <span class="test">SHABOO</span>
  <div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</body>
```

In the outlet, a component is rendered and it contains the following.

```
<span class="test">HAZAA</span>
```

I expected it to get the same style as the first one but it seems that the style doesn't cascade down to the component. It made me uncertain if I'm mistaken about how the styles are supposed to behave between parent and child components in Angular.

I made sure that the name of the class isn't overriden (to exclude the risk of collision). At the moment, I'm putting similar chunks of SCSS code in each component and that's obviously bad practice.

If I `@import "../app.component.scss"`, the styles kicks in. But I was under the impression that even without the import, the style is supposed to cascade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular components use [***view encapsulation***](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation). This is by design so that components are reusable across applications. To treat a component's styles as *global*, set the view encapsulation mode to `none` (*not recommended*).

Instead of using `none`, register global style files in the [Angular CLI styles section](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles), which is pre-configured with the `styles.css` file.

> Component CSS styles are encapsulated into the component's view and don't affect the rest of the application.
>
> To control how this encapsulation happens on a *per component* basis, you can set the *view encapsulation mode* in the component metadata. Choose from the following modes:
>
> - `ShadowDom` view encapsulation uses the browser's native shadow DOM implementation (see [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM) on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) site) to attach a shadow DOM to the component's host element, and then puts the component view inside that shadow DOM. The component's styles are included within the shadow DOM.
> - `Native` view encapsulation uses a now deprecated version of the browser's native shadow DOM implementation - [learn about the changes](https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/).
> - `Emulated` view encapsulation (the default) emulates the behavior of shadow DOM by preprocessing (and renaming) the CSS code to effectively scope the CSS to the component's view. For details, see [Appendix 1](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#inspect-generated-css).
> - `None` means that Angular does no view encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML.
>
> To set the components encapsulation mode, use the encapsulation property in the component metadata:

#### src/app/quest-summary.component.ts

```
// warning: few browsers support shadow DOM encapsulation at this time
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
```

[`ShadowDom`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation#ShadowDom) view encapsulation only works on browsers that have native support for shadow DOM (see [Shadow DOM v1](https://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdomv1) on the [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/) site). The support is still limited, which is why **`Emulated` view encapsulation is the default mode and recommended in most cases**.

## [External and global style files](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#external-and-global-style-files)

> When building with the CLI, you must configure the `angular.json` to include *all external assets*, including external style files.
>
> Register **global** style files in the styles section which, by default, is pre-configured with the global `styles.css` file.
>
> See the [CLI wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles) to learn more.

Comment: So, to verify that I got that right - you're saying that the behavior I'm experiencing is correct, by design, and that the cascading I was referring to isn't a product of my confusion/imagination but simply not active by default in Angular. Correct? So, if I simply import the global SCSS everything will be just dandy. Or am I missing something that's going to come back and bite me in the sitting device?

Comment: @DonkeyBanana Correct, the behavior of isolating styles to components is by design. For styles that should apply application wide, use global styles, such as the default top level `styles.css` (or `styles.scss`).

Comment: And by using global styles, you mean that I have an `@import` statement at the top of my individual SCSS files, right? That's acceptable and reasonable.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana The standard approach is to specify global styles in files that are added to `angular.json` in the `styles` config option. The `styles` config option is defined as "An array of style files to add to the global context of the project." See [**Styles and scripts configuration**](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-and-scripts-configuration). It is also possible to `@import` styles as needed.

Answer (score 4):

This is how angular works. Every component is separated with it's CSS, even if it is child component of a parent. They can't inherit their parent CSS.

Haza span component is child of your app component, but it is separated component. So, you can't get those Shaboo styling to Haza.

**Solution:**

if you want to maintain same CSS, there are multiple ways.

1. Recommended way:

   a) if it is only for onle class, copy the class to the child component.

   b) if it is for huge number of classes, create a css file for them and import them in both parent and child component css. 
   Example:

   @import '../span.css';
2. you can add this css to styles.css. then you will get it anywhere in the app. if you want this style many places, you can do it.
3. As @Christopher Peisert mentioned, by using

   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
   end of the @component decorator in child.component.ts. It is not recommended way

Answer (score 0):

The global CSS files are those that are listed in angular.json. All others CSS files are encapsulated by default (this can be removed but is not recommended.)

Keeping your global CSS organised is important as your application grows. What I like to do is create a global styles folder and then add new files for different widgets that I might be altering. Since removal of ::ng-deep these types of changes have to be done in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

It works like that. If you are in need of having a common style then add it in the global styles.scss file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a global style put it in the global file `styles.css` or styles.[Your css preprocessor]

See this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5ntm6?file=src%2Fstyles.css

I put test class at the end

```
.test{
  color:red;
}
```